# Finding the zeros of a function using sequences

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x) = 1 + x^2 -10sin(x)$. Show that $f(x)$ has at least one zero in $(0, \infty)$.

-$f$ is continuous for all x.

-Let $x_n = (0.001)n$, $n = 0,...,10^6$

-Evaluate: $y_n = f(x_n)= 1 + ((0.001)n)^2 - 10sin((0.001)n)$, $n = 0,...,10^6$

-If $y_n * y_{n+1} < 0,$ then $\exists x \in (10^{-3}n, 10^{-3}(n+1))$ such that $f(x) = 0$.

-Proof of concept:

-Let n = 101, then

$$y_{101} \approx 0.001917 $$ $$y_{102} \approx -0.007828 $$ $$\Rightarrow y_{101} * y_{102} <0$$

-Thus $\exists x \in (0.101, 0.102)$ such that $f(x) = 0$.

-$f$ has a root at $x \approx 0.101197$

So clearly, this is just trial and error. My first thought for how to show that $f(x)$ has AT LEAST one zero in $(0, \infty)$ was to show that $y_n = f(x_n)$ is always decreasing since this would imply that $y_{n} * y_{n+1}$ would eventually have to produce a negative number, thus implying that a zero exists in the original function, but this is clearly not the case as $y_n = f(x_n)$ is not monotone decreasing over the entire $(0,\infty)$. Any thoughts as to how I can show that this concept has to produce a negative number for a certain n?

Comment: if $f(x)$ is some smooth function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, a root finding algorithm consists in two steps : first locate an interval $[a,b]$ where $f$ changes of sign, i.e. $f(a)f(b) < 0$, then find the precise location of the root by reducing the bounds, i.e. from $[a_n,b_n]$ with $f(a_{n})f(b_{n}) < 0$ get a smaller interval $[a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]$ such that again $f(a_{n+1})f(b_{n+1}) < 0$.

Comment: of course we also require that $\lim_{n \to \infty} |b_n-a_n| = 0$, i.e. we can get better and better approximation of the root location. the dichotomic method allows $|b_{n+1}-a_{n+1}| = |b_n-a_n|/2$, which converges "fastly", hence the problem is more the first step : locating an interval $[a,b]$ where $f(a) f(b) < 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the *Intermediate Value Theorem*. We have  $f(0)=1$, and $f(\pi/6)$ is negative.  Since $f$ is continous, it follows that $f(x)=0$ for some $x$ between $0$ and $\pi/6$.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm seems like the [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) of root finding. It works well for most functions, except that it is rather slow.

Be careful with your assumptions. You can have a positive sequence which is always decreasing, like $y_n=1/n$.

The algorithm is not guaranteed to work because you can only test a finite number of points, but your domain is unbounded. Your example tested numbers from $1$ to $1000$. Even if you tested points from $1$ to $1000^{1000}$, I could still invent  function whose only root is bigger than $1000^{1000}$. Also, the function might have two roots very close together so that the function goes very quickly from positive to negative to positive again. If the roots are close enough together, your finite grid doesn't "see" them. Finally, for some functions, like $x^2$, there is a root, but the function is never negative. The bisection method fails for such functions.

For more analytical methods, see the intermediate value theorem.